# Problems with typoscript rules after upgrading TYPO3 from v4 to v7

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

i've upgraded TYPO3 from version 4.6.16 to version 7.6.23 and there seems to be a breaking change or something else, that these Typoscript-Rules are not working anymore:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    #100 < tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
    #100.15.value = vtwBlue
}
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    key.field = section_frame
    100 = TEXT
    100.value = <div class="right-column">|</div><div class="right-column-bottom"></div>
}

tt_content.stdWrap {
     innerWrap.cObject = CASE
     innerWrap.cObject {
         200 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
         200.15.value = block
         200.30.value = ><div class="block-inner color-frame">|</div></div>

         210 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
         210.15.value = block
         210.30.value = ><div class="block-inner color-frame-right-space">|</div></div>
    }
}
```

**Basically i need this construct:**

```
<div class="csc-default">
    ...
</div>
```

Modified to:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-inner color-frame">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**The real base is:**

```
<div id="c1270" class="csc-default">
    <div class="tx-accordion">
      <h1>test headline</h1>
      <span class="imgr">
          <img class="rund" src="..." width="50" height="50">
      </span>
      <p class="acSeminarStart">Test Name</p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <p class="bodytext"></p>
      <p class="bodytext">
          <a href="...">Mehr</a>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Result should be with 'csc-default' -> 'block' and an additional wrapping div 'block-inner color-frame':**

```
<div id="c1270" class="block">
    <div class="block-inner color-frame">
        <div class="tx-accordion">
          <h1>test headline</h1>
          <span class="imgr">
              <img class="rund" src="..." width="50" height="50">
          </span>
          <p class="acSeminarStart">Test Name</p>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p class="bodytext"></p>
          <p class="bodytext">
              <a href="...">Mehr</a>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And another Block:**

```
 <div id="c2582" class="csc-default">
    <h3>Test title</h3>
    <div class="tx-lightbox">
        <div class="lightboxImage">
            <span class="imgr" style="">
                <img class="rund" alt="Slideshow" src="..." width="300" height="240">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="lightboxText">
            <p class="bodytext">Test description</p>
            <span class="counter">23 Pictures</span>
            <a class="group2582 cboxElement rzslideshow" href="...">jetzt anschauen</a>
        </div>

        <a class="group2582 cboxElement rzslideshow" style="display:none;" href="..."></a>
        <a class="group2582 cboxElement rzslideshow" style="display:none;" href="..."></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**With this wanted result:**

```
<div id="c2582" class="block">
    <div class="block-inner color-frame">
        <h3>Test title</h3>
        <div class="tx-lightbox">
            <div class="lightboxImage">
                <span class="imgr" style="">
                    <img class="rund" alt="Slideshow" src="..." width="300" height="240">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="lightboxText">
                <p class="bodytext">Test description</p>
                <span class="counter">23 Pictures</span>
                <a class="group2582 cboxElement rzslideshow" href="...">jetzt anschauen</a>
            </div>
            <a class="group2582 cboxElement rzslideshow" style="display:none;" href="..."></a>
            <a class="group2582 cboxElement rzslideshow" style="display:none;" href="..."></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no clue what's wrong. Exactly this typoscript was working in TYPO3 V4.6.18 :(

Comment: did you directly upgraded to 7 version ?

Comment: I've updated from version 4 to version 6, fixed the broken plugins and than to version 7 and again fixed broken plugins and some database entries

Answer (score 0):

here is the changed Typoscript, what to need after the TYPO3 Update testet with TYPO3 v6.

```
    tt_content.stdWrap {
     innerWrap.cObject = CASE
     innerWrap.cObject {
         200 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
         200.20.10.value = block
         200.30.cObject.default.value = ><div class="block-inner color-frame">|</div></div>

         210 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
         210.20.10.value = block
         210.30.cObject.default.value = ><div class="block-inner color-frame-right-space">|</div></div>
    }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very very very much! It's working :)

Comment: How did you've found those numbers?
Is it something which is documented or something which can be inspected somewhere?

Comment: This is not documented. I have checked and compare your code with Template > Object Browser in TYPO3 Backend ;)